# IonSelect and ionCheckBox not working when binding with Array variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic2

I am doing an app with ionic 2 angular 2 and typescript. I wanted to create an ionSelect for every Passenger of Passengers (of a flight):

```
<div *ngFor="let Pass of Passengers; let i=index">
  <ion-item no-lines>
    <h2 item-left>{{'PERSONS'|translate}}</h2>
    <ion-select item-right [(ngModel)]="Passengers[i].PersonType"  placeholder="" (ionChange)="CONSOLES()">
      <ion-option value="Bébé (0-2)"> {{'BABYPERSONTYPE'|translate}}</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Enfant (2-12)">{{'ENFANTPERSONTYPE'|translate}}</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Jeune (12-24)">{{'YOUNGPERSONTYPE'|translate}}</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Adulte plus 24">{{'ADULTPERSONTYPE'|translate}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

As you can see I am loading the passengers from an array of Objects: Passengers and in each of those objects i have a value named PersonType that should have the person type chosen via the ionSelect for a particular Passenger.

The problem is that whenever i change an ion select value for one passenger, all the other passengers get their values changed as well.

Here is a Picture of my app :

[image]

What i wanted to say is that when i change the value of the first passenger from "Adult above 24" to an other value, all passengers get their values changed too and this is not intended to happen.

**NOTE** : I tried the Binding of the ion select with **[(ngModel)]="Pass.PersonType"** but it didn't work either.

**NOTE** This exact problem happens with ion Checkboxes when they are bound to values inside arrays

So what is the problem?

Comment: Can you show me the `CONSOLES()` code?

Comment: It is just a console.log(this.Passengers)

Comment: Can you share `Passengers` array?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Passengers Array holds at start one passenger object :
  `passenger ={
  PersonType:"Bébé (0-2)",
    Name:"",
    Birth:new Date("1970-01-01"),
};` 
and then will be filled dynamically with the same objec type whenever the user clicks on the add button

Comment: i tried to produce your problem but couldn't. all working as expected. can you reproduce here. https://plnkr.co/edit/HJvZq6?p=preview;

Comment: This is really weird, i recreated the problem but it never created any problem in the plunker

Comment: Ah there it is, it turns out that if i dynamically add the person objects the problem would occur so the first hardcoded object has no problem what so ever. just open the plunker and try to add 3 new passangers and change one

Comment: @MedMansour As said before, the Plunker works fine, where is the issue reproduced?

Comment: Please provide your .ts file

Comment: @AJT_82 The Problem occurs with pushed objects, so if i preload the array with 3 passenger objects, the problem doesn't happen, but if i add 2 more via pushing (array.push()) the problem will occur, i did reproduce it in the plunker but i guess i didn't save it.

Comment: Well could you reproduce it now, modify the plunker and *save* it (hehe) and give the link, and I'd be happy to take a look :)

Comment: Well to be honest, i fixed the issue. this issue happens only if i push the object by its name: so if i define the pasenger object :
`passenger ={ PersonType:"Bébé (0-2)", Name:"", Birth:new Date("1970-01-01"), };`
and then push it like this : `PassengerArray.push(passenger)` the problem will occur. But if i push the object this way :
`PassengerArray.push({ PersonType:"Bébé (0-2)", Name:"", Birth:new Date("1970-01-01"), })` the problem won't come out, which is what i did.
Plunker with problem :https://plnkr.co/edit/r2I91vADsfi2OdLShPmr?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, I kind of suspected this was the issue ;) Yes, if you push `passenger`, **ALL** objects have the same reference, so if you change one, all change, since they are all the same object :)

Comment: Well how do i create a new reference for the pushed objects ?. I still have the problem with checkboxes, which can't be fixed by just pushing the object directly since i have to go through filling the object before pushing it.

Comment: I wrote you an answer, hopefully it's suitable for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per seen in plunker you are pushing the same object `passenger` to your array:

```
this.Passengers.push(this.passenger);
```

This means that every time you push the passenger, all objects have the same reference. So whatever you do to one object, will affect the other objects as well.

This can be solved using `Object.assign` which assigns the values from `passenger` to a new object:

```
this.Passengers.push(Object.assign({}, this.passenger));
```

**[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/1cIh3RbeYnTo1ugyH58y?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Comment: Glad to hear it work! Have a nice weekend and happy coding! :)